# Getting TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when running Jest Tests in Parallel

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, backend

I am getting the following error when running Jest Tests in parallel.
When running each test individually or when using --RunInBand, they all pass and seem to work fine.

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:181:21)

node:internal/child_process/serialization:159
    const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
                   ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:159:20)
    at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:845:17)
    at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:745:19)
    at reportSuccess (C:\Users\User1\Documents\App1\App2\api-gateway\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:82:11)
```

I expected all tests to run and succeed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue when enabling a custom Connection Pool on the ElasticSearch.js client. Removing this eliminated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why this happens, but the Jest Worker has a circular-reference object in the test result (e.g. a HTTP connection).

Use a Debugger and set a breakpoint on line 82 of
`node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js`

```
function reportSuccess(result) {
  if (!process || !process.send) {
    throw new Error('Child can only be used on a forked process');
  }
  process.send([_types.PARENT_MESSAGE_OK, result]);  // set a breakpoint here
}
```

You can then see the errors under the `testResults` property of `result`.

[image: debugger]